# Rails 3 + Devise 1.3.4: How to log in using a username?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I know there are tons of tutorials already that explain how to do that, but I've been spending way too much time trying to make it work without success...

Official doc: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign_in-using-their-username-or-email-address

In the official doc they explain how to log in using the username OR email. I just want to log in using the username only.

What I've done:

```
1.  rails generate migration add_username_to_users username:string
2.  rake db:migrate
3.  rails generate devise:views
```

My app/models/user.rb: (I only added :username in attr_accessible)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

end
```

My config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
 ...
 config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
 ...
```

My app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb:

```
...
  <p><%= f.label :username %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :username %></p>
...
```

I believe this is all there is to change, but it will just say "invalid email or password".

Thank you for your help..!

Comment: Although it doesn't solve you problem. The "invalid email or password" message is in config/local/en.yml user devise:failure:invalid
If you are changing it to validate username, you should change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change lines in `config/locales/devise.en.yml`. Change:

```
invalid:email or password
```

To:

```
invalid:username or password
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you overwrited find_for_database_authentication method like asked on the Devise documentation you provided?.

Something like this:

```
protected

def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  login = conditions.delete(:login)
  where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
end
```

Should make it work.

Comment: This is in case you want to have 2 kinds of login, I just want to keep 1, but a different one. I don't think I should change this - that's at least what I saw on articles.
What file does this def have to be written into? I'm still a beginner.. :)..

Comment: No, i've already changed the where condition on the method to keep only the username one. You have to add it on the User model (app/models.user.rb) as noted by Jhonny.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `app/models/user.rb`

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(conditions={})
  self.where("username = ?", conditions[:username]).limit(1).first 
end
```